# Google AppEngine Failed to compile jsp files. mac os

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, jsp, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to deploy my Java EE project on GoogleAppEngine on eclipse (Indigo/ mac os X lion).
But I have an error:

```
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.JspCompilationException: Failed to compile jsp files.
```

I checked my JRE path, it seems to be good. Maybe a library?
Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1):

To compile `jsp` files you need the `JDK`. The `JRE` does not help here.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Where can i check my jdk?

Comment: I found my error, i use java code : 

    pourcentage1 = total1 *100.0 / marks.size();

And compiler doesn't know .size() function.

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: I hope this helps: http://manski.net/2011/12/30/eclipse-and-the-jdk-under-mac-os-x-lion/